# Eclipse ADT Error: Cannot run program adb

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adb, adt

I'm on Ubuntu and just installed the Android SDK ("SDK Only") for 64-bit linux. I then installed the ADT plugin for Eclipse. When I restarted Eclipse it asked me to open the SDK Manager and install some OS SDKs, so I installed some Developer tools and the most recent (I believe it was 4.2.2) Android distro. I then restarted Eclipse and got no errors or console warnings.

I then tried to open several Android views (Heap, LogCat, etc.) and got the following error:

[image]

What is this and why am I seeing it? What can I do to correct it? Thanks in advance!

**Update:** running an `ls -l` on the directory in question produces:

```
myUser@myMachine:~$ ls -l ~/sandbox/dsi/workbench/android-sdk/21.1/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
total 27960
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myUser myUser  1122758 Apr 11 10:29 aapt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myUser myUser  1226659 Apr 11 10:29 adb
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myUser myUser   269818 Apr 11 10:29 aidl
drwxrwxr-x 2 myUser myUser     4096 Apr 11 10:29 api
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myUser myUser   444481 Apr 11 10:29 dexdump
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myUser myUser     2603 Apr 11 10:29 dx
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myUser myUser   176550 Apr 11 10:29 fastboot
drwxrwxr-x 2 myUser myUser     4096 Apr 11 10:29 lib
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myUser myUser 24867619 Apr 11 10:29 llvm-rs-cc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myUser myUser   467531 Apr 11 10:29 NOTICE.txt
drwxrwxr-x 4 myUser myUser     4096 Apr 11 10:29 renderscript
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myUser myUser    16648 Apr 11 10:29 source.properties
myUser@myMachine:~$
```

Comment: Someone deleted or modified ADB or Android SDK. Make sure the ADB path it shows in the error is correct. And IMHO you should not put the Android SDK inside your Eclipse workspace.

Comment: Thanks @m0skit0 (+1): (1) The path `/home/myUser/sandbox/dsi/workbench/android-sdk/21.1/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb` is valid, and ADB is located there, so it hasn't been removed. And (2) just curious, why do you think the Android ASK is in my Eclipse workspace? the `workbench/` directory has 2 child folders: `android-sdk`, and `eclipse`. My Eclipse workspace is in `workbench/eclipse/workspace`. Just want to make sure you don't see something else that I'm missing. Thanks again!

Comment: Could this be a linux/permissions issue?

Comment: Sorry, I read *workspace* instead of *workbench*. And I highly doubt this is a permission problem or a Linux issue. I develop Android mostly on Linux and never had this problem. Can you please run `ls -l ~/sandbox/dsi/workbench/android-sdk/21.1/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools` in a terminal and show the output?

Comment: Thanks again @m0skit0 - please see my update and let me know what you think.

Comment: Please put the exact command you used and the current logged user as well. I think you're not referencing the correct `/home` directory.

Comment: "ls -l" was the command and I just string-replace my actual user name with "myUser" (for privacy reasons) inside gedit.

Comment: Sorry but I said `ls -l ~/sandbox/dsi/workbench/android-sdk/21.1/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools`, not `ls -l`.

Comment: No problem @m0skit0 - please see my updated terminal output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is your Ubuntu Version ? 
Before ubuntu 12.04, you must install  ia32-libs

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: @IAmYourFaja Try to move your folder out of the Home folder (like /sdk)

Comment: It won't let me; copying the ANDROID_SDK_HOME to /opt/android-sdk isn't allowed, even with a sudo. I get a "omitting directory" message.

Comment: create the folder /sdk et move the content of folder "android-sdk" in this /sdk folder
Why you try to move in /opt/ ?

Comment: The error is "No such file or directory". I don't think this has anything to do with ia-32-libs.

Comment: but it helped me. I just set up a my new laptop and, of course, forget that package :D

Answer (score 8):

If you're on ubuntu 13.10 (and possibly other versions >= 12.10), you may need to install

```
apt-get install lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6 zlib1g:i386 libc6-i386
```

in stead. ia32-libs is no longer available on 13.10