# unable to start my adb

Tags: android, adb

It is showing an IOException. I am using Ubuntu Release 12.04 (precise) 64-bit, 1.9 GB RAM,  Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5200 @ 2.50GHz × 2.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried reducing the memory allocated (when creating the adb in eclipse) for the adb?

Comment: This might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912548/android-adb-unable-to-open-sync-connection?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the i-a32 libs which are not installed by default on 64-bit machines.
Check the accepted answer [Eclipse ADT Error: Cannot run program adb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15951778/1833437) 
 or simply try :

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```